# Exclude Series from Default/Auto Visible Range - Lightweight Charts

Tags: javascript, lightweight-charts

We're using line series to plot moving averages, and occasionally the moving averages are far enough away from the price series (candlesticks) that the price series becomes very small and compressed when lightweight charts auto-sizes the visible frame. A solution to this would be to allow the chart to exclude certain series when setting the visible range. Is this possible? If there is not an API (and far as I can tell there is not), then is there a hack/workaround? This would be particularly useful when using line series for trendlines.

Answer (score 0):

Within the [options for a Series](https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/docs/api/interfaces/SeriesOptionsCommon) you can define your our function for the autoScaling ([autoScaleInfoProvider](https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/docs/api/interfaces/SeriesOptionsCommon#autoscaleinfoprovider)).

So for the series which is plotting the moving average, you could override the auto scaling behavior and rather return the min and max values of your choosing. For example, you could also have an `autoScaleInfoProvider` on the main series so you can get the values that it is providing for the autoScale, save them somewhere, and then return `null`. You could then use those saved values for when the moving average `autoScaleInfoProvider` is called.